# Array not populating correctly

Tags: php, arrays, count, loops

I am using the following code to populate an array:

```
$number = count ($quantitys);
    $count = "0";
    while ($count < $number) {
        $ref[$count] =  postcodeUnknown ($prefix, $postcodes[$count]);  
        $count = $count +1;
    }
```

postcodeUnknown returns the first row from a mysql query, using a table prefix and an element from an array named postcodes. $postcodes contains strings that should return a different row each time though the loop.

Which I'd expect to create an array similar to:

```
Array ([0] => 
       Array ([0] => some data [1] => more data) 
[1] => 
       Array ([0] => second row [1] => even more...)
)
```

But it's not. Instead it's creating a strange array containing the first results over and over until the condition is met, eg:

simplified result of print_r($ref);

```
Array (
   [0] => Array ([0] => some data [1] => more data)
) 
Array(
   [0] => Array (
        [0] => the first arrays content... 
        [1] => ...repeated over again until the loop ends
     )
)
```

And I'm at a loss to understand why. Anyone know better than me.

Comment: I was just formatting your question and realised the 2nd array doesn't look correct... can you update with correct output. Thanks

Comment: That's the whole point of the question. It isn't formatting correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$number = count ($quantitys);
$count = "0";
while ($count < $number) {
    $ref1[$count] =  postcodeUnknown ($prefix, $postcodes[$count]);
    $ref2[] =  postcodeUnknown ($prefix, $postcodes[$count]);
    $ref3[$count][] =  postcodeUnknown ($prefix, $postcodes[$count]);
    $count = $count +1;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($ref1);
print_r($ref2);
print_r($ref3);
echo "</pre>";
```

Try that to see if any of those get an output you are looking for.

Comment: None of these have worked. I'm going to try gutting the unknownPostcode function and check it for faults.

Comment: Fixed. I tried your suggestion - no luck. However I then tried changing count ($quantitys) to count ($postcodes). Which shouldn't of effected anything as they are always arrays of the same length, It worked anyway.

Comment: Ok, if unknownPostcode returns an array then $ref[$count] = unknownPostcode() should work.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, add a print to postcodeUnknown and check if its actually passing different postcodes or the same thing all the time?

ie

```
function postcodeUnkown($a,$b){
    echo var_dump($a).var_dump($b);
    //the rest
}
```

Also, why two different variables? ($quantitys and $postcodes).

Also, you might want to replace the while loop with for:

```
for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++){
    $ref[$i] =  postcodeUnknown ($prefix, $postcodes[$i]);        
}
```

Comment: This has not fixed the malformed array problem. As far as I can tell the root of the issue is something to do with the $count iteration.

 While postcodeUnknown is being called the appropriate number of times, it seems to call with $postcodes[0] regardless of how many times the loop has run. I am using MAMP by the way for development.

Answer (score 0):

your variable count should not be a string, try this

```
$number = count ($quantitys);
    $count = 0;
    while ($count < $number) {
        $ref[$count] =  postcodeUnknown ($prefix, $postcodes[$count]);  
        $count = $count +1;
    }
```

Comment: This won't be the problem as PHP will still increment a string, by turning it into an int

Comment: checked this to be sure - no change.